# Custom content type template in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress and working on a website change. The website was developed by another developer.

The wordpress version is 3.4.1

It has an Advanced field group called 'Films' which has certain custom fields as 'Title', 'Date of release', 'duration' 'trailer video' etc.

The site uses advanced custom fields and has a template as 'content-films.php". This page pulls the content for any film and displays.

I need to develop a pay-per-view page for films where user will be able to watch the entire film after payment through paypal.

I am stuck at the template selection. the 'content-films.php' is a page with films description and a trailer video embed. I need to create one more template  to implement the pay-per-view page for each film.

I could not find any documentation on the implementation of templates as 'content-films.php' . I found some for single-post_type.php but my site is not using that.

Please help me in the approach on which template should I create to implement the pay-per-view page for films

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a page template. Name it anything you want, for example test.php, and put it in the theme folder In the beginning of this file you will have to put a comment which tells wordpress that this is a page template.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Test
*/
?>
```

Then create a new page from the wordpress admin and assign it to the template you just created (dropdown on the right side of the editor).

Comment: There are already a page template in the site and there are multiple page contents. Will this not affect the films page template. Also I coulnd't find the dropdown to attach the template